# Failed to login to SMTP server: DOT project

Tags: php, smtp, dotproject

i cannot send emails using dotproject management system , i am unable to figure it out why it is giving me error : Failed to login to SMTP server:
My SMTP settings

```
Email Transport:SMTP
SMTP host: ****.webhostbox.net
SMTP port: 465
Host requires login : checked
smtp username: username@hostname
password: ********
smtp server timeout: 30s
Enable TLS for smtp: checked
```

please help me if i am missing anything.

Comment: For TLS you usually use port 587, instead of 465, which is historically used for SSL.

Comment: While changing port to 587, now i am getting this error                                    "Failed to login to SMTP server: 503 AUTH command used when not advertised"                                                                                                                    everything else is perfectly set, as i am using same configuration in my other app that work perfectly.